# Manually initiate authentication using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to create an UnderConstruction page for my new site.

I would like to retain all the core files (files that are part of the site) without modification while I try to implement this. This includes leaving the index.php intact.

Currently, I have an .htaccess setup to authenticate on any access to the site.
I want to redirect any user accessing any page (at least the index.php) to an UnderConstruction page and then leave a link there which my dev team could use to authenticate themselves and continue using the site as usual.

But in order to leave the core files intact, I would have to initiate the htaccess type authentication & then in index.php (assuming that index.php is excluded from the cuth) check the auth status.

I tried to play around with  `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` but these (as I understand) requires me to manually implement the authentication scheme (ie checking against a list of username & passwords).

I'm working on an apache with php5 on a linux server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont you jsut mirror the dev version of the site to a subdomain like `dev.mysite.com` and then keep the under construction stuff on the main domain? This way you can secure the dev domain however, and still keep your under construction page going.

Comment: @prodigitalson, This was exactly the thing that I should have been looking for. Please post this as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just mirror the dev version of the site to a subdomain like dev.mysite.com and then keep the under construction stuff on the main domain. This way you can secure the dev domain and still keep your under construction page going and the two will be isolated.

Answer (score 0):

put this on htacces for each file u wanna lock

```
Redirect /file.extension http://www.uroot.com/index.php
```

Comment: Could you explain how this would help in my case. I'm trying to ensure that a casual user don't require any authentication while still allowing my team access to an intact site after authentication.